# Halt goes into uninterruptable state while shutting down - how can I shut down?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, halt

I have had a hard drive failure which has caused a lot of processes to go into an uninterruptable state ("D" state in `ps`- [See this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/244891/how-do-i-stop-and-repair-a-raid-5-array-that-has-failed-and-has-i-o-pending)). I cannot kill these processes, so I wish to shut down, but unfortunately `halt` is also now showing as "D" and the machine will not restart!

```
ben@jack:~$ ps aux | grep "halt"
root      7875  0.0  0.0   4148   700 ?        S    Mar08   0:00 /bin/sh /etc/rc0.d/S01halt stop
root      7880  0.0  0.0  10436   680 ?        D    Mar08   0:00 halt -d -f -i -p
```

How can I recover from this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your system has it enabled, you can probably use [Magic SysRq](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key) to force a shutdown or reboot.  Otherwise hopefully you have a network-accessible power supply you can log into?  Then you can power-cycle the outlet the host is connected to.

Or maybe you have iLO or ipmi on the box, and you can log in to one of those to force a power cycle?

And of course as a last resort, it's time to send a flunky onsite.

Comment: `echo b > /proc/sysrq-trigger`

Comment: Spot-on, the print screen key has never been so useful! Thanks!